# Leitura de um editText - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

Tenho um *app* onde é feito uma leitura de um json e retornado em uma *list* todos os itens desse json.
Estou utilizando o *ADAPTER* para fazer isso, eu coloquei um `EditText` na tela, esse editText é replicado a cada item lido do json.
Exemplo
1- produto (`EditText`) QTD:
2- produto 2 (`EditText`) QTD:

E assim por diante, minha dificuldade está em Ler esses `EditText` 1 por 1, estou utilizando um `FOR` hoje para alterar a *Qtd* de cada um e dar um *update* no banco, mas ao colocar `QTD = 5` por exemplo no primeiro item e `qtd = 10` no outro, ele replica o 5 para os outros itens na hora do update.

Segue meu `Activity`:

```
carrinho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String url = HOST + "/listaCarrinho.php";
            String idc = "162";
            Ion.with(getBaseContext())
                    .load(url)
                    .setBodyParameter("idCarrinho", idc)
                    .asJsonArray()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {

                            try {
                                String qtd = "";
                                for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
                                    JsonObject obj = result.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                                    String IDCarrinho = Integer.toString(obj.get("id").getAsInt());
                                    Log.d(IDCarrinho, "onCompleted: IDCarrinho");
                                    EditText quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtd);

                                    String idedit = Integer.toString(quantidade.getId());
                                    Log.d(idedit, "onCompleted: IDEdit");

                                    qtd = quantidade.getText().toString();
                                    Log.d(qtd, "onCompleted: quantidade");
                                    String url1 = HOST + "/updateQtd.php";
                                    String idcar = "162";
                                    Ion.with(getBaseContext())
                                            .load(url1)
                                            .setBodyParameter("quantidade", qtd)
                                            .setBodyParameter("id", IDCarrinho)
                                            .setBodyParameter("idcarrinho", idcar)
                                            .asJsonObject()
                                            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                                                    try {
                                                        String RETORNO = result.get("UPDATE").getAsString();
                                                        if(RETORNO.equals("OK")){
                                                            Toast.makeText(CarrinhoActivity.this, "O PEDIDO FOI FINALIZADO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        } else if(RETORNO.equals("ERRO")){
                                                            Toast.makeText(CarrinhoActivity.this, "NÃO FOI FINALIZADO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        } else {
                                                            Toast.makeText(CarrinhoActivity.this, "Ops ocorreu um erro,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        }
                                                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                                                        e1.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                    carrinhoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            carrinhoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
        }

    });
```

Segue meu *Adapter*:

```
    private Context ctx;
private List<Carrinho> lista;


public CarrinhoAdapter(Context ctx2, List<Carrinho> lista2){
    ctx = ctx2;
    lista = lista2;


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

@Override
public Carrinho getItem(int position) {
    return lista.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = null;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)ctx).getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carrinho_lista,null);
    } else {
        v = view;
    }

    Carrinho c = getItem(position);
    EditText Qtd = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.qtd);
    TextView Prod = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.prod);




    Qtd.setText(String.valueOf(c.getQtd()));
    Prod.setText(c.getNome());

    return v;
}[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi do código, você está iniciando seu edittext e de forma síncrona tenta recuperar o valor dele. Dependendo do caso o certo é usar algum botão que o usuário indica quando salvar o formulário ou algo do tipo, ai no evento desse botão você recupera o valor passado pro EditText.

Comment: Você diz, colocar 1 check por exemplo em cada item? ai faço if checked... da o update?

Comment: Tipo isso. Infelizmente estou sem o pc, pra poder te ajudar na sua situação em específico. Aqui nesse [link](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/) ele mostra algo parecido com o que você precisa. No caso desse exemplo ele utiliza um listener quando tira o foco do edittext recupera os valores nele. Você pode tentar implementar esse exemplo pra você.